# redirecting users away from sign in page after login in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

I would like my users to be redirected to the home page if they visit "/users/sign_in" after they have already signed in. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller action for the sign in page (registrations probably if you are using devise).  You will have to override the controller if you haven't already.

```
def new    
  if current_user
    redirect_to home_page_url
  else
    #current logic for sign in method (super) if you currently don't have it implemented
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I also discovered a way of doing this from the router.rb file; that is much much easier than doing it from the router, which would require me to override the devise controllers.

```
  authenticated :admin do
    root :to => 'admin/dashboard#show'
  end

  authenticated do
    root :to => 'dashboard#show'
  end

  root :to => 'landing#show'
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your routes.rb:

```
  match "user_root", :to => "site#show"  # where SiteController#show is your home page
```